# Zeep got an unexpected keyword argument in operation

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, zeep

I'm trying to send a request to a [WSDL WebServices](https://testws.punto-web.com/wcfadproc/srvproceso.svc?wsdl). According to [documentation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wotMp8bkXtU619HCys8Jmt-Ib_JYsrf/view?usp=sharing), the requests must be formatted in XML.

I'm using Python and Zeep module. The operation a want to use is called 'Consulta' and parameters are called 'Comercio' and 'NumPedido' (first one is numeric type and second is alphanumeric).
The code I've tried is the following:

```
from zeep import Client, Settings

settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client('https://testws.punto-web.com/wcfadproc/srvproceso.svc?wsdl', settings=settings)

request_data = { 'Comercio': '8004749', 'NumPedido': '7030510'}
client.service.Consulta_Marca(**request_data)
```

But this gives me error  `` TypeError: {http://tempuri.org/}Consulta_Marca() got an unexpected keyword argument 'NumPedido'. Signature: `xml: xsd:string` ``

Can anyone give me some advice about fixing this? Because seems that the operation is correct, but do not why the parameters are bad.

**EDIT:**

I've tried this little new code

```
from zeep import Client, xsd, Settings
settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
client = Client('https://testws.punto-web.com/wcfadproc/srvproceso.svc?wsdl', settings = settings)
parameters = xsd.Element(
    'Consulta',
    xsd.ComplexType([
        xsd.Element(
            'Comercio', xsd.Integer()
        ),
        xsd.Element(
            'NumPedido', xsd.String()
        )
    ])
)

parameters_values = parameters( Comercio=8004749, NumPedido='7030510')
operation = client.service.Consulta_Marca(parameters_values)
operation
```

This gives me another error

```
The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'Consulta_Marca'. End element 'xml' from namespace 'http://tempuri.org/' expected. Found element 'Comercio' from namespace ''. Line 2, position 465
```

But think I'm closer because if I execute
`client.service.Consulta_Marca(parameters)`, I get a valid response, but with null values because no parameters values were passed.

Please some help!